# Shopware 6 : How To Load Categories From Repositories on Storefront

Tags: shopware

I am new to shopware 6 and I am not getting the flow how data is displaying on the frontend? Can anyone please help me load categories on the storefront?

Here is the screenshot of categories to display on frontend:

[image]

Comment: You wanna get the data in a own controller, or extend an exisiting page?

Comment: i have created custom controller from storefrontcontroller with custom page the route is example/category . so i need  to load categories on my custom page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To load entities in shopware 6 you can require the service  `sales_channel.category.repository` which is an instance of `\Shopware\Core\System\SalesChannel\Entity\SalesChannelRepositoryInterface`.
With this object you are able to search for the wanted categories.

You can add the needed `SalesChannelContext` as a parameter of your Route function, shopware will auto fill it if you add the right RouteScope.

See also the shopware docs for this:
https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/storefront/add-custom-controller#adding-custom-storefront-controller